# How to make a swipe enabled photo gallery (using photos from photo library)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, photo-gallery, photolibrary

I'm making an ios camera  application which is written in swift, and I want to add an album in the app. I'm using [ALCameraViewController](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController)
framework. It creates a nice collection view of the photos, which fetch all the photos from user's Photo Library. And when you tap on one of image cell, it can also show the single image.

But which I want is that, in the single image view, user is able to swipe left and right to get to the previous and next photo. My idea now is to add all the photos into an array, so it can loop in the array to show different images. But this may cause the app to crash due to the less of memory. Is it possible that every time when user swipes left or right, then the program will fetch the photo? Or any other way to make this?

Any idea? thanks~

Comment: Use `collectionView `. Only that memory is allocated that is appeared in the UI. if cell is disappeared from the screen then its memory is released.

Answer (score -1):

You can check below framework. It is very easy to implement.

https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

It has a FullScreenSlideshowViewControllerclass which can be used for your purpose, also it can be customised.